# /dev/random being used after tls handshake

Tags: java, performance, ssl

I'm looking at a performance issue and my question is the following.

After TLS handshake has completed, is there any further reliance on `/dev/random`?

If I run with the default random source, the performance is significantly lower than using `file:/dev/./urandom`. For the benchmark the same secured socket connection is used for 10m; so it isn't that we create new connections all the time.

So I understand that random source is needed during the handshake, but it isn't clear why random source is needed during regular data-transport.

[update]
I'm using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 as ciphersuite.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, since TLS itself is not an encryption mechanism, and /dev/random is used by the actual cryptographic scheme that's used when a secure channel is initiated using TLS.  Also why ARE you switching it from /dev/urandom to /dev/random? Is it because you believe that /dev/random is "truly" secure where as /dev/urandom is not? That's not true (if you understand crypto). For an overview I suggest you read this http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/ to understand the differences and set the defaults back to /dev/urandom

Comment: and the reason your program is slowing down is because /dev/random blocks when it runs out of entropy, you should NOT be using it for CSPRNG operations.

Comment: hi pventjeer, your question remains unclear until you specify which crypto scheme you're using for your TLS connection, and include some benchmarks (hint: if on Linux, `perf top`). Maybe you're just transmitting random data, taken from `/dev/random`?

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'm benchmarking between default configuration which is /dev/random and /dev/./urandom. I see that the latter has better performance than the former; but I'm failing to understand why this should matter once the handshake is out of the way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256.

Comment: if you are using CBC SHA256 then the algorithm may be padding the blocks using data from the random pool, which would mean that it's constantly trying to read from /dev/random, and when that runs out of entropy the process blocks.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedMasud. If you can enter that as a answer, I can vote  for that.